What makes a compound lexical if it uses an auxiliary that can be attached to any verb?
I'd like to understand more about lexical compound verbs, specifically, lexical compounds that include an auxiliary that can be used with any verb. The verb 残す is an auxiliary that can be attached to any verb to mean "not finish verb" or to "leave verb unfinished" although I've noticed that in addition to being able to be attached to any verb and being syntactic, there are also a few lexical compounds using this auxiliary, one being 食べ残す (to leave a dish partially eaten). I would like to know what makes them lexical? Why are they classified that way if 残す can be attached to any verb? I'm asking here because it is extremely difficult - if not impossible to find anything on this subject. Thank you in advance!

What to include as a separate entry in a dictionary is a rather arbitrary decision. There seems to be no really good reason to include 食べ残す while excluding 飲み残す.

I'd say it's completely based on usage and convention. For example, 追いかける is so common that it's in every dictionary you could find, yet 追い走る is not a commonly used word and therefore not found in dictionaries. It's like how "undo" is in English dictionaries but "unopen" or "undestroy" is not, even though the two are equally comprehensible to a fluent speaker. It's up to the lexicographers to cherry-pick.

@dvx2718 thank you! This is rather helpful

Compound Verb Lexicon is your go-to website for this type of information. Interestingly, they list 残す as one of the 30 syntactic verbs, and yet they list the following combinations as "lexical":

Among these, 言い残す, 書き残す, 思い残す, and 取り残す (as in 部屋に取り残される) have unpredictable meanings other than "leave partly undone", so they are justifiably lexical. However, 食べ残す, し残す, and 積み残す don’t have tricky meanings, so I don't understand why they are listed here.
On the other hand, I feel -残す is not entirely syntactic, either. Some combinations such as 降ろし残す, 脱ぎ残す and 受け残す sound unfamiliar and awkward to me. Even though it's classified as syntactical, I don't think it can combine with just any verb.
Ultimately, we must conclude that it is difficult to categorize this verb entirely on one side. At least, the meanings of verbs like 取り残す and 思い残す must be memorized. Even for other combinations, there are common ones and practically nonexistent ones, so you need to get used to them over time.

After a bit more research and figuring out the concept of "fixed meanings" I've come to understand that syntactic compounds can also be lexical if they have a fixed meaning. 食べ残す has a fixed meaning. It conveys an already established idea of leaving food partially eaten,that is it's concrete meaning. The meaning does not change with usage and is interpreted by speakers of the language as leaving food partially eaten. 飲み残す on the other hand does not. It can be interpreted as: leave drink unfinished,to partially drink it,to not drink it,to drink some and leave it behind. It's not as concrete 1/2

It's a little tricky and honestly strange but it has to do with productivity in linguistics. These words convey such a fossilized meaning that they become lexical. There are also some combinations with a syntactic compound that have a completely random meaning,an example being Omoidasu (to recall a memory) this is considered lexical because of the meaning not matching the combination of its separate parts and being a completely random fixed meaning,in turn it is lexical HOWEVER it can be used in a syntactic sense to say "to start to think" if you're simply going off of the separate parts 2/2

(Responding here temporarily, but I might delete my comments later)

I happened to notice that Compound Verb Lexicon site on https://vvlexicon.ninjal.ac.jp/en/ says: "Termination of Publication of Compound Verb Lexicon on this Website || We regret to inform you that the long-standing compound verb lexicon will no longer be available on this site as of September 30, 2024. We have decided to continue its availability on the following two websites with a new look. We hope you will continue to use the new and improved compound verb lexicon. || NINJAL Site（https://www2.ninjal.ac.jp/vvlexicon/） || j-minato（https://j-minato.jp/vvlexicon/） ||" …

… "The data for the compound verb lexicon can be downloaded from the Institute for Japanese Language and Linguistics repository (https://doi.org/10.15084/0002000261)."

It seems that several links across japanese.stackexchange.com will have to be updated. (https://www2.ninjal.ac.jp/vvlexicon/about.html has general description of phenomenon of compound verbs, which was on original site.) (NINJAL site works for me, but j-minato site does not work for me currently.)
